# Problems with the Text Views

Tags: xml, android-layout, textview

I am facing a strange behavior of my text view. I have already constrained both 'Sleep Timer' text view and the 'this feature ...' text view, but somehow when I run it on my emulator, I couldn't see the 'Sleep Timer'. Here's a screenshot of my Emulator: [image]

this is my layout.xml codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivSleep"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="210dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="101dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="101dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvTitle2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sleep" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle2"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="148dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="148dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="121dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="121dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/textView_pgTitle2"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvDesc2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesc2"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:text="@string/textView_pgDesc2"
        android:textColor="#575757"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is my string.xml codes:

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Music Player</string>
    <string name="textView_pgTitle1"> Search Bar </string>
    <string name="textView_pgDesc1">The Search bar allows you to search for anything and everything
        in Planet Music!</string>
    <string name="textView_pgTitle2"> Sleep Timer </string>
    <string name="textView_pgDesc2"> This feature can be found in Settings. Music will stop playing
        when time is up. </string>
    <string name="textView_pgTitle3"> Settings </string>
    <string name="textView_pgDesc3"> Settings can be found at the top right hand corner of
    Planet Music. </string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the height of tvTitle2 element is limited to 30dp. Either you increase it or  change it to wrap_content or reduce the font size.

Comment: I have changed the height to wrap_content, and even reduced the font size. but my emulator still displayed the same results. Increasing the constrains between 'Sleep Timer' and 'this feature...' still showed the same results.

Comment: Can you use linear layout instead so there can be less attributes to achieve the same ui